# Foreign key в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли сделать Foreign Key в одной таблице на другую, для которой данное поле **НЕ** ключевое?

Причем интересуют следующие движки:

- MyISAM
- InnoDB
- Memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. По определению :)